# How many mice will be eaten?

Tags: mathematics

A cat and a half eats a mouse and a half for an hour and a half.
How many mice will be eaten by 100 cats for 100 hours?

Answer (score 3):

> 10,000.  Half a cat eats no mice.

alternately...

> 100 - because the rest of the mice will run away over the course of the hour where each cat is eating their first mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> $6666 \frac{2}{3}$

Reasoning

> In an hour and a half, $N$ cats eat $N$ mice. Therefore the number of mice eaten by $100$ cats in $100$ hours will be $100 \times \frac{100}{3/2}$

Comment: That's the correct answer.